# I have a list view.how i will save list view total number of click to another activity text view?

Tags: java, android

I have a list view, how can I save a list view total number of clicks to another activity text view?

I have custom list view, it has money TextView and a name TextView.  When I clicked on list view total number of clicks save on another activity text view.

example like..

list view item=5

1st item clicked->another activity text view have one value.

2nd item clicked->another activity text view have two value.(prevoius and new value)

Comment: Let's try to help you. You want to know how many times the list was clicked and show this number in the Text view of a new activity ? Am I correct?

Comment: yes You are correct @JDenais

Comment: save the number in sharedpreference.

Comment: @vincentzhou can u give me a link like my above problem?

Comment: @sundersharma http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm

Comment: @sundersharma http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html You can update the value in preference every time you click and retrieve the number to update textview in onResume() of another activity

Comment: I think storing the value in shared prefs is a good idea if the firts activity is not the starting point of the new activity. Otherwise it is less efficient than using intent.

Comment: @vincentzhou thanks But My eject requirement is check my link   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30341896/i-want-this-like-screen-sort-i-want-to-action-bar-value-is-update-every-clicked

Answer (score 2):

Use can use SharedPreferences for this...

```
int count=0;

SharedPreferences pref=getSharedPreferences("share",1);

Editor edit=pref.edit();


    if(pref.contains("count"))
    {
        count=pref.getInt("count", 0);
    } 


//Do this code in OnItemClickListener()..

list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            count++;
            edit.putInt("count", count);
            edit.commit();
            Intent intent=new Intent(getActivity(),PersonalChat.class);



            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Now in second activity ...

    SharedPreferences pref =getSharedPreferences("share",1);
  
  if(pref.contains("count"))
  {
   
   Log.e("pref count", pref.getInt("count", 0)+"");
  }

Answer (score 0):

You can have a countClicks int in your activity and pass this int in the intent when you create the new Activity.

Catch the click like this :

```
int countClick = 0;

list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
    countClicks ++;
        }
    });
```

Comment: I suggest you show us your code. It will be easier to help.

Comment: thanks @JDenais But My eject requirement is check my link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30341896/i-want-this-like-screen-sort-i-want-to-action-bar-value-is-update-every-clicked